# number of row error with ggplot2 histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a problem with using ggplot2 to generate histograms. I'm using the following function, which receives input, a data.frame. The function only has to create a data.frame as you can see. But I get an error indicating that the number of rows in each column is different. Any idea? I am using RStudio, Is it a problem of the library ggplot2? if so, is there any other library that serves to make histograms? I tested with barplot but I get an error margins ...

my function:

```
HIST_EPC_list<-function(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter){
    require(ggplot2)
    ggplot(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter, aes(x=DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Tag_PHASE, y=DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Num_EPC))+xlab("PHASE")+ylab("Number of EPC's")+ ggtitle("Histogram of Number of EPC/PHASE")+geom_histogram(stat="identity")

    #barplot(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Num_EPC, names.arg = DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Tag_PHASE, xlab = "Tag_PHASE", ylab = "Num_EPC", main="Histograma Num tags/PHASE:", width=10)
    #par(mar=c(4,4,4,4))
}
```

example of data.frame `DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter`

```
  Tag_PHASE Num_EPC
1      101.0       1
2      120.0       1
3      146.0       1
4       16.0       1
5      163.0       1
6       25.0       1
7       42.0       1
8       53.0       2
9       56.0       1
10      61.0       1
11      64.0       3
12      75.0       1
```

THE ERROR:

Error in data.frame(x = 1:8, y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), PANEL = c(1L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 12

Comment: That code, with that example data, with the same names, works for me.

Comment: every time I ran it gives me error ... any idea what could it be?Error in data.frame(x = 1:8, y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), PANEL = c(1L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 12

Comment: somewhere its getting a data frame with only 8 elements, and a PANEL column. Where's that come from? You've not passed the right thing to the function. Try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the table name when specifying the `aes` if you want to use the data parameter that you are passing in to the plot. You should use

```
HIST_EPC_list<-function(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter){
    require(ggplot2)
    ggplot(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter, aes(x=Tag_PHASE, y=Num_EPC))+
      xlab("PHASE")+ylab("Number of EPC's")+ 
      ggtitle("Histogram of Number of EPC/PHASE")+
      geom_histogram(stat="identity")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the error, which used the same system as used with barplot